# Add Excel Cell to SQL Where clause

Tags: sql, excel, where-clause, powerquery

I have the following sql query pulling data into Excel(2016) using Power Query:

```
Select SUM([Period Balance]) from AccountSummary 
Where [Account Number] = '3010-0000'
AND Year = '2018'
AND [Period ID] = '5'
```

I want to replace '5' with an excel cell reference such as Sheet1!B1.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the cell value by selecting it in the worksheet and using From Table in the ribbon. Make sure that you uncheck "this table has headers". You can drill down in the table to get the cell value.

If the query generated by From Table is named Query1, then there are a couple options:

1. If you are using the Query parameter for `Sql.Database`, you can use the `&` operator to join 2 Text values together, like `"AND [Period ID] = '" & Query1 & "'"`. Note that this approach does not protect against SQL injection, so if you want to protect against that you need to escape Query1 (e.g. use Text.Replace to double all instances of `'` and `]`)
2. You can use `Value.NativeQuery` and pass in Query1 as a parameter, like so: `Value.NativeQuery(Source, "AND [Period ID] = @id", [id = Query1])`

Answer (score 0):

Click on the cell where you have the parameter and click on Create a new query from selected table option inside the Data tab. Add the below code

```
() =>  Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="YourTableName"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]
```

Rename this query to something like Param() and you can use this in any queries to get the parameter value like

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Other Columns", each [jobtitle] = Param())
```